# Upgrading CentOS 7.4 to CentOS 7.7

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

How do I upgrade CentOS 7.4 image to CentOS 7.7, and not CentOS 7.8? The latest kernel in the update repos is 7.8, but I cannot find a 7.7 kernel in the repos.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this: You have to enable the mirrors for specific version in CentOS-Vault.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/, and disable the CentOS-Base mirrors.